# Python cut XML-file

Tags: python, xml

After some reserche I succeded in cuting my XML-file as the picture showes.

The main ide being that if a child is "red" then its parent should be removed. If the Grandparent dosn't have children left a few levels down the whole grandparent should be removed.

I used Python and lxml for this and it is the `getparent()` thing I don't know if I got rigt. It seams to be right. Someone might be kind and explain why it works, please!

[image]

But I do not know if I made some misstake in my thinking.

The remaining transactions seams to be the right ones.

The code as belowe:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ETT
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('files/Test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# remove Transactions if tag <child> don't start with the text "Abc".
for tag in root.xpath('.//Transaction'):
    if not tag.xpath('.//child[starts-with(text(),"Abc")]'):
        tag.getparent().remove(tag)

# This is the part I tried and it actually worked, I think it should cut higher up in the XML-tree as the part above does.
for tag in root.xpath('.//VoucherHeader'):
    if not tag.xpath('.//child'):
        tag.getparent().remove(tag)

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("files/out.xml", encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

I used the line `tag.getparent().remove(tag)` twize and I dont realy get how it can work the second time. It should cut the bransh at the same level as "tag" in the loop, witch it seams to do but if it actually referes to the parent why dosent it cut higer up then the looping element.

Comment: It seems much easier to implement via XSLT. Please edit your question, and add the following: (1) input XML, (2) desired output.

Comment: Interesting I had no clue abour something like XSLT, thanks could come handy.

Comment: Good. Please provide ##1-2, and logic how to get from #1 to #2.